# Удивительное перспективное деление (C++)

Tags: c++, математика, матрицы, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

В моем softwre-renderer есть проекция точек при помощи матрицы и последующее перспективное деление.

В целом код выглядит так:

```
void DrawSector(gfx::ImageBuffer<RGBQUAD>* imgBuffer, const math::Mat4<float>& vpMatrix, const World& world, size_t sectorIndex)
{
    auto sector = world.getSector(sectorIndex);

    for(const auto& wall : sector->getWalls())
    {
        size_t pointsPerPrimitive = wall->vertices.size();
        for(size_t i = 0; i < pointsPerPrimitive; i++)
        {
            // Индексы двух точек
            size_t i0 = i;
            size_t i1 = ((i+1) > (pointsPerPrimitive-1) ? 0 : i+1);

            // Две точки в пространстве
            auto v0 = wall->vertices[i0];
            auto v1 = wall->vertices[i1];

            // Проекция (в NDC пространство)
            auto v0T = vpMatrix * math::Vec4<float>({v0.x, v0.y, v0.z, 1.0f});
            auto v1T = vpMatrix * math::Vec4<float>({v1.x,v1.y,v1.z,1.0f});
            v0T = v0T / v0T.w;
            v1T = v1T / v1T.w;

            // Перевод в координаты экрана
            auto v0S = math::NdcToScreen(math::Vec2<float>(v0T.x,v0T.y),imgBuffer->getWidth(),imgBuffer->getHeight());
            auto v1S = math::NdcToScreen(math::Vec2<float>(v1T.x,v1T.y),imgBuffer->getWidth(),imgBuffer->getHeight());

            // Нарисовать линию
            gfx::SetLine(imgBuffer,v0S.x,v0S.y,v1S.x,v1S.y,{0,255,0},gfx::SAFE_CHECK_ALL_POINTS);
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге я получаю примерно такую картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, если какие-то точки уходят за границы frustum'а видимости, происходит такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно понимаю почему это происходит, и я решил попробовать "малой кровью" устранить этот эффект, чтобы вершины не выворачивало при уходе их за границу frustum'а.

Заметил что 4-ая компонента (которая участвует в перспективном делении после умножения матрицы на вершину) становится отрицательной как раз когда точка выходит за frustum.

Решил попробовать просто ограничить ее каким-то значением:

```
// Проекция (в NDC пространство)
auto v0T = vpMatrix * math::Vec4<float>({v0.x, v0.y, v0.z, 1.0f});
auto v1T = vpMatrix * math::Vec4<float>({v1.x,v1.y,v1.z,1.0f});
v0T = v0T / std::max(v0T.w,0.01f);
v1T = v1T / std::max(v1T.w,0.01f);
```

В итоге выворот вершин устранился, но появились небольшие искажения перспективы при определенных углах.

Подумал что эти искажение сможет исправить уменьшение ограничивающего числа (я не мог использовать 0, поскольку это было бы деление на ноль), и я решил просто чуть уменьшить, например до 0.001f. В итоге эффект искажения действительно уменьшился, НО:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё начало просто дичайшим образом тормозить, будто бы производятся какие-то титанические вычисления! И чем меньше я делал ограничивающее значение, тем сильнее были тормоза.

Еще пытался убирать max вовсе, и просто вбивал туда 0.001f без всяких условий - и тормоза сохранялись!

- Что это вообще такое?
- Откуда такие тормоза?
- Неужели банальное деление на маленькое float значение - такая тяжелая операция для процессора?
- Должно ли так вообще быть или это следствие какого-то моего косяка, который я где-то допустил?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить профилировщик, чтобы узнать, из-за чего происходит замедление

Comment: И ещё попробуйте описать задачу текстом без кода более подробно. Например, что такое softwre-renderer? Проекция каких точек и куда? Что такое frustum?

Comment: @dIm0n, это все термины из Computer Graphics, зачем их объяснять?

Comment: @eanmos ответы на первый и второй вопросы вряд ли можно найти без ТС. На третий -- возможно, но в интересах ТС увеличить потенциальную аудиторию ответчиков, приведя хотя бы ссылку для ознакомления

Comment: @dIm0n, если человек не знаком с теорией CG, то он не сможет ответить на этот вопрос. Если знаком -- все эти термины он и так знает.

Comment: @eanmos вы можете ответить на мои вопросы?

Comment: @dIm0n, не знаток CG, но: 1. Software renderer -- рендеринг на CPU вместо GPU. 2. Проекция точек из world space в NDC. 3. Frustum -- область отсечения, т.е точки, попадающие в эту область будут видны на экране. По-моему, так.

Comment: Чем меньше число на которое вы делите, тем длиннее линия которая получается. Я говорю про линию в экранной плоскости и её длину в пикселях. Можно предположить что алгоритм рендеринга пробегает пикселы линии и фильтрует по непопаданию на экран. Всё время тратится на порождение координат пикселов которые будут отсечены. Клиппинг не зря придуман. Отрежьте ваши линии по границам пирамиды зрения (включая ближную плоскость) и рендеринг пройдёт быстро и без искажений.